# Google App Engine Flex - ASP.net core 2.1

Tags: asp.net-core, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

Need your help. I just want to locate the published files (physical files published) of my .NET Core 2.1 in the App Engine server. I used Google plugin tool to publish my site and everything is done automatically.

I'm using simple app.yaml file:

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
```

I tried to scan some folders of the App Engine server but I could not locate my site. I also wonder maybe because google uses docker (don't have experience with docker too) and those file are in the docker's container. Not really sure.

Comment: Could you clarify if you want your app to read the published files? Or is it more that you want to know "where the deployed files went to"?

Comment: Hi Jose V, thank you so much for the reply. I just want to know where my deployed files went to. 

Basically I just want to backup my sqlite db because when I republish my app (using the "google tool plugin") because even if i'm using the same version instance of the App Engine I think it will delete all my previous files (deployed files).

Answer (score 0):

In your project's Cloud Storage Buckets list, you will find a Bucket named like `artifacts.[project-id].appspot.com`. There you will find the container images that were deployed to App Engine.

However, App Engine provides On Demand server provisioning and scaling. This means that App Engine instances will be created when requests start coming in and more instances will be created if traffic increases.

Each instance will load your app's image individually.

In this type of environment, you should not store any relevant information in the App's directory, because all of it will be erased when the instance is killed due to lack of traffic and the data stored in one instance will not be available in other instances. See [how instances are managed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/how-instances-are-managed) for more info.

If you want your app to store data in a SQL database, you could have a look at [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql), or also, you may find that [Cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore), which is a NoSQL database, can suit your needs. Here is a [list of GCP databases](https://cloud.google.com/products/databases)

Comment: Thank you so much Jose V. Yes I get your point. But still I just want to know where my files went to, on what particular folder.

Comment: I am afraid you won't be able to get them. Other than the container image files I mentioned on my answer that can be accessed via Cloud Storage, when an image is loaded into an instance, there is no way to access it's files other than via the app itself. Moreover, when the instance is killed, its files are deleted with the instance